# My private repository became Not Found even if global GitHub account is defined after two-factor authentication is setup

Tags: github

I setup Two-factor authentication in my GitHub account.
Then, I generated my personal access token in GitHub and used it in order to clone my private repository.
However, it failed.

```
$ git config --get user.name
myusername
$ git clone https://github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git
Cloning into 'MyPrivateProject'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git' not found
```

"myusername" has access permission and could exactly access to my private repository before two-factor authentication was setup.

Then, I tried following command and it worked well.

```
$ git config --get user.name
myusername
$ git clone https://myusername@github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git
Cloning into 'MyPrivateProject'...
remote: Repository not found.
Cloning into 'ambie_co_jp'...
Password for 'https://myusername@github.com': <Personal Access Token>
remote: Enumerating objects: 475, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (475/475), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (351/351), done.
remote: Total 475 (delta 96), reused 470 (delta 92), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (475/475), 38.96 MiB | 5.06 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (96/96), done.
```

I don't understand why I need to write "myusername@" in repository URL though "myusername" is already defined in .gitconfig as global user.

Could you give me any advice ??

Comment: `user.name` isn’t the name that’s used for authentication, it’s the name stored in your commits.  If you need to use a username to authenticate, provide it when prompted or in the url.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thank you for your comment. 
May I know how to provide username ?

Answer (score 0):

After 2FA is setup, you would [need to use a PAT as password](https://help.github.com/articles/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication/), as shown here:

```
https://scuzzlebuzzle@github.com/<user>/<repo>
<enter <MYTOKEN> as password>
```

Those should be cached by a [credential manager](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) (like the [GCM for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)).

Comment: Thank you. Now `$ git clone https://myusername@github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git` is OK. I don't need to enter PAT. However, what I expect is `$ git clone https://github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git` . I don't want to enter my user account name in the url. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ken yes: if you have a credential manager in place, it will display a popup for you to enter your username and PAT there (once). Then any git command to that private repo won't ask you anything anymore, since your credentials will be cached.

Comment: Thank you. 

`[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain`

is written in ".gitconfig", however, git command does not show any popup to ask my user account name.

Comment: @ken possibly because it is already cached? Try and edit or delete that entry in the keychain, as in https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/.

Comment: As you mentioned keychain already stored username and password(=PAT). I deleted it, then I did `$ git clone https://github.com/xxx/MyPrivateProject.git` without "username@". It resulted in fatal error(Not Found)...